# Fascinating limits? (highschool)

Tags: limits, soft-question

I wonder if there is someone who knows any cool limit who they're are willing to share. I have just started using them in highschool and is interested in learning more.

Comment: What would you call *fascinating*? Limits aren't very fascinating...

Comment: Depending on your age (I'd say at least 17 for most bright mathematicians) GH Hardy's "Pure Mathematics" is a decent source of limits and their possibilities.

Comment: Let $\pi(x)$ be the number of primes $\le x$. Then $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{x/\ln x}=1$.

Comment: I would strongly disagree with the statement that limits aren't fascinating, as all of mathematical analysis has been called the "art of taking limits."

Though not as interesting as Andres example, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(1+1/n)^{n^2}}{e^n}=1/\sqrt{e}$.

Comment: FYI, G. H. Hardy's [A Course of Pure Mathematics](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/38769) is available _gratis_ (typeset in LaTeX, with modernized notation and re-created diagrams) from [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Mathematics_%28Bookshelf%29), or in [HTML](http://books.sayahna.org/hardy-html/) from the Sayahna Foundation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: Oh, if series count, then: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n k =-\frac{1}{12}$$ (according to my string theory book)

Comment: this one is really fascinating :O

Comment: @Shahar Not in the convential definition of convergence though.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\pi(x)$ be the number of primes $\le x$. Then 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(x)}{x/\ln x}=1.$$
This is the famous [**Prime Number Theorem**.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)

Answer (score 3):

1) The epxonential function $f(x)=e^{-x}$. Here take the limit $x \to \infty$

[image]

2) The function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Here take the limit $x \to 0$ and $x \to \infty$

[image]

3) The function $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$. Here take the limit $x \to 0$

[image]

4) And (sorry to disappoint you), but things some times do not converge and they oscillate for ever....

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$

Comment: It might be worth mentioning here - as OP is a high-school student - that `x` here is expressed in radians, rather than degrees.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac x n\right)^n=e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Falls out of Stirling's approximation, but it's still cool:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln n!}{n \ln n} = 1 $$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\underset{\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2\le1}{\int\ldots\int}1\ dx_1\ldots dx_n=0$$

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite: $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody posted this yet:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{i\pi}{n} \right)^n = -1
$$
Or:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(i\pi)^k}{k!} = -1
$$

Comment: Well, technically this is just a special case of Cristoph's answer...

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x$
$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=a$.
simple. but construct compution of limit of polynomials